# How would I condense these separate labels to an array of labels in my custom UICollectionView cell?

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This code works perfectly fine, but I am assuming there is a much more efficient way of doing things like this. I am providing the first four items of an array of strings (this list can contain an unlimited amount of variables) to the user as a "snapshot" view. The code below is inside of a custom cell class.

```
var tray: Tray? {

    didSet {
        guard let trayTitle = tray?.title else { return }
        guard let trayItems = tray?.items else { return }
        // tray.items will give an array of strings
        trayTitleLabel.text = trayTitle

        if trayItems.count == 1 {
            firstSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[0]
            secondSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            thirdSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            fourthSnapshotLabel.text = ""
        } else if trayItems.count == 2 {
            firstSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[0]
            secondSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[1]
            thirdSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            fourthSnapshotLabel.text = ""
        } else if trayItems.count == 3 {
            firstSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[0]
            secondSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[1]
            thirdSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[2]
            fourthSnapshotLabel.text = ""
        } else if trayItems.count >= 4 {
            firstSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[0]
            secondSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[1]
            thirdSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[2]
            fourthSnapshotLabel.text = trayItems[3]
        } else {
            firstSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            secondSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            thirdSnapshotLabel.text = ""
            fourthSnapshotLabel.text = ""
        }
```

I then manually set up each label:

```
let firstSnapshotLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text:"Item 1", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let secondSnapshotLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text:"Item 2", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let thirdSnapshotLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text:"Item 3", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let fourthSnapshotLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text:"Item 4", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()
```

As I said, the code above gives me what I wanted, but it is extremely messy and inefficient.
Here is something else I've tried that didn't quite work. I am assuming that the "snapshotLabels" were loaded into the view before the "snapshots" array was populated. I assume this because when I print the "snapshots" I get the populated array, but when I print the "snapshotLabels" I get an empty array.

```
var tray: Tray? {

    didSet {
        guard let trayTitle = tray?.title else { return }
        guard let trayItems = tray?.items else { return }
        // tray.items will give an array of strings
        trayTitleLabel.text = trayTitle

        for item in trayItems {
            snapshots.append(item) 
        }
    }
}

var snapshots = [] as [String]

    lazy var snapshotLabels = snapshots.prefix(4).map { item -> UILabel in
        let label = UILabel()
        label.attributes(text:"\(item)", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
        return label
    }
```

Tray struct and array of instances:

```
struct Tray {
let title: String
let items: [String]
}

let trays = [Tray(title: "Groceries", items: ["Apples","Water","Milk","Eggs","Fruity Pebbles","Bread","Butter","Flour","Yogurt","Pop-Tarts"]),
             Tray(title: "Home", items: ["Laundry","Trash","Clean desk"]),
             Tray(title: "Miscellaneous", items: ["Call mom","Feed dogs"]),
             Tray(title: "Bucket List", items: ["Skydiving","England","Pilot's license","Learn spanish","Barcelona","Italy"]),
             Tray(title: "Dinner", items: ["Pasta","Crabs","Tacos","Pizza","Steak","Cheesesteaks","Chicken and Rice"])
]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Make your labels an array

```
  let labels = (0..<4).map {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text:"Item \($0)", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: 0.5, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
  }
```

then iterate over your tray items to set the value on the corresponding label

```
  (0..<trayItems.count).forEach { labels[$0].text = trayItems[$0] }
  (trayItems.count..<labels.count).forEach { $0.text = "" }
```